# Existence of (anti)perovskite (Cs+)3(Pt2-)(Au-) and (Cs+)(Ba 2+)(Au-)3

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, transition-metals, ionic-compounds, alkali-metals, alkaline-earth-metals

I know that there are oxide-aurides of cesium and rubidium from wikipedia and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243821351_Cs3AuO_the_First_Ternary_Oxide_with_Anionic_Gold and that the component compounds cesium/barium auride/platinide exist. Would a double salt be able to exist with these components?

(may have to get Au- and Pt2- radii from lattice parameters)
(CsAu a = 4.24 angstrom)(Crystal data of Cs2Pt: hexagonal, spacegroup P63/mmc (No. 194), a=567.6(1), c=947.1(3) pm, V=264.3(1)×106 pm3, ρcalcd=5.783 g cm−3, Z=2, μMoKα=39.86 mm−1, F(000)=376, λ=71.073 pm,)

Comment: There are certain areas of chemistry where we may say with a good deal of confidence that such-and-such compound exist, even though it has never been obtained. This is **not** such area.

Comment: I'd bet we find [caesium(>I)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/950/4/042055) first.

Comment: alkaline metal anions do exist, but the cation must be protected by ligands like EDTA